# How to control the Zoom of a WebView in android when a TextField in WebView is Clicked

Tags: android, keyboard

Guys i have a WebView in my Screen with some TextFields in it. Whenever i click on a TextField my keyboard is opening along with that my WebView is Zooming automatically.How to resolve it.Any Suggestions

Thanks&Regards,

Venkat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try overriding the standard behaviour of your webview by using a WebViewClient.
More info on those can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html). Numerous examples of the implementation of the WebViewClient can be found by simply googling it.